# Scala execute command on windows

Tags: scala, command-line-interface

How can I execute command in a "fire and forget" fashion using Scala ?
So far I have written this snippet :

```
Process("export_vars_cmd && start /B myprocess > NUL 2>&1").!
```

, but when I fire up my Scala application, it executes the command, and keep waiting instead of exiting.

Comment: The `!` method blocks until the process terminates. You might try `run()` instead. But note that the child process will receive a TERM signal when Scala terminates.

Comment: I have tried run(), but it doesn't make any difference generally speaking, is there a way to completely detach the process ?

Comment: I don't think a parent can detach a child, but a child can detach itself by forking. The original process terminates with an exit status while the copy process proceeds on its merry way.

Comment: Thanks for help. I think that I will try to find another approach instead.

Comment: What always works is wrapping it in a `Future { ... }`